# How does Delphi XE7 handle Multiple Threading in Parallel Tasks

Tags: multithreading, delphi, parallel-processing, task

I am new to parallel programming and am trying to find out why I occasionally get an EmonitorLockException:Object lock not owned when I increase the number of parrallel tasks to run. Is the case that the Threads become tangled the more tasks I run. Or is my code code not correct?

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
System.SysUtils, System.Threading, System.Classes, System.SyncObjs, System.StrUtils;

const

WorkerCount = 10000; // this is the number of tasks to run in parallel    note:when this number is increased by repeated factors of 10
                  // it takes longer to produce the result and sometimes the program crashes
                  // with an EmonitorLockException:Object lock not owned . Is it that my program is not written correctly or efficiently to run
                  // a large number of parallel taks and the Threads become entagled.
                  // Eventually I would like to optimeize the program to find the optimal number of tasks to run in parallel so as to find the result in the shortest time.
                  // This becomes important when the word sequence is increased to six or more letters.

sequencetofind='help'; // letter sequence to find randomly
sequencelengthplus1=5;  // the ength of the letter sequence plus 1 extra   letter for a check to see if it is working


var
  Ticks: Cardinal;
  i,k,m: Integer;
  sequencenum: Integer;
  alphabetarray:array[1..26] of string;
  v:char;
  copyarray,letters:array[1..sequencelengthplus1] of string;
  tasks: array of ITask;
  LTask: ITask;
  Event1:TEvent;
  sequencesection:TCriticalSection;

  function findsequencex(index: Integer): TProc;    
  begin
    Result := procedure
              var
                counter,m:integer;
                r:integer;
                z:string;
                lettersx:array[1..sequencelengthplus1] of string;
              begin
                for m:=1 to sequencelengthplus1-1 do
                  lettersx[m]:=letters[m];
                randomize;
                counter:=1;
                repeat
                  r:=random(26)+1;
                  z:=alphabetarray[r];              //randomly find letters until matched    with the sequence

                  if z=letters[counter] then 
                  begin
                    copyarray[counter]:=z;
                    counter:=counter+1;      // increase counter when successfully found a match
                  end
                  else 
                    counter:=1;       // if match fails start again and look for the first letter

                  if (counter=sequencelengthplus1) then 
                  begin      // if all letters found in correct order find one more letter as a check

                    sequencesection.Acquire;                   //critical                  section start
                    r:=random(26)+1;
                    z:=alphabetarray[r];

                    TInterlocked.CompareExchange(sequencenum,r,0);
                    copyarray[sequencelengthplus1]:=z;
                    Event1.SetEvent;                                 // set in motion the process to stop all other tasks
                    sequencesection.release;                    // critical section end
                  end;
                until (Event1.WaitFor(0)=wrSignaled);      // check to see if all letters of the sequence has been found
              end;
  end;



  procedure Parallel2;
  var
    i,sequencevalue,j: Integer;
  begin
    Event1:=TEvent.Create(nil,true,false,'noname');    // sequence checker
    Event1.resetevent;
    sequencenum := 0;
    Ticks := TThread.GetTickCount;
    SetLength(Tasks, WorkerCount);             // number of parallel tasks to undertake
    for i := 0 to WorkerCount-1 do
      Tasks[i]:=TTask.Run(findsequencex(i));
    TTask.WaitForAny(Tasks);             // wait for the first one to   successfully finish
    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
               procedure
               begin
                 for LTask in Tasks do
                   LTask.Cancel;                                  // kill   the remaining tasks
                 TInterlocked.Add (sequencevalue, sequencenum);   // note   the random letter check
               end);
    Ticks := TThread.GetTickCount - Ticks;
    writeln('Parallel time ' + Ticks.ToString + ' ms, last random alphabet sequence number: ' + sequencenum.ToString+' random letter is = '+alphabetarray[sequencevalue]);
  end;
begin
  sequencesection:=TCriticalSection.Create;
  for m:=1 to  (sequencelengthplus1-1) do
  begin
    letters[m]:=copy(sequencetofind,m,1);
    writeln(letters[m]);
  end;
  i:=0;
  for v:='a' to 'z' do
  begin
    i:=i+1;
    alphabetarray[i]:=v;
  end;
  try
    begin
      Parallel2;    // call the parrallel procedure
      writeln('finished');
     for m:=1 to sequencelengthplus1 do
       writeln(copyarray[m]);
     if (Event1.WaitFor(0)=wrSignaled) then 
     begin
       writeln('event signaled');
       if (sequencenum=0) then writeln('sequence is null');
     end;
     Event1.Free;
     sequencesection.free;
   end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
 end.
```

Comment: Ouch, you should try formatting the code properly. It will make a huge difference to the readability.

Comment: Why are you calling TThread.Synchronize from the main thread?

Comment: I was thought it will help to sychronize the threads so they would not become locked

Comment: No, that's not what it does. You have to understand this area to have any hope of success. Parallel programming is orders of magnitude harder that serial programming.

Comment: In addition LTask.Cancel() doesn't make sense since you are not checking task's status anywere in your code. Cancel() does not magically "kill" or terminate tasks.

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound, please do not remove spaces from around operators in the name of "improving formatting." Many people find that the spaces improve readability.

Answer (score 9):

You've got masses of shared global variables that you access without any synchronization. For instance:

```
  if z = letters[counter] then
  begin
    copyarray[counter] := z;
    counter := counter + 1;
    // increase counter when successfully found a match
  end
```

Here `copyarray` is a global that is shared between all the tasks. This data race alone could result in the error you see. There are other similar races. And I am sure that there are many many more problems. The entire code cannot be salvaged. You need to throw it away and start again.

Here are some tips:

1. Pick a simpler task to begin learning about parallel programming.
2. Find a good book or tutorial on the subject. Start small and work up to your actual problem.
3. Stop using global variables. Sharing data with globals can only lead to pain. Sharing is your enemy. Keep it to a minimum.
4. If you need to share data do so in an explicit manner rather than using globals. And make sure the access to shared data is synchronized.
5. Don't call `Randomize` from inside your thread. It's not threadsafe. Call it once at startup.
6. `Random` is not threadsafe. Find a thread safe PRNG, or synchronise calls to `Random`. The former option is to be preferred.
7. Don't call `TThread.Synchronize` from the main thread.
8. Manage lifetime the standard way. When you create an object, use `try` and `finally` to protect its lifetime. Don't create objects in one function and destroy them in some other function.
9. Format your code so that it is readable. If you cannot read your code, how will you ever understand it?
10. With the greatest of respect, it's clear that you've not mastered serial programming yet. You should aim to be proficient at serial programming before moving to parallel programming. Parallel programming is at least an order of magnitude harder.
11. With that in mind, try to write a good, clean version of your program in serial form. Then think about how to transform it to a parallel version.

Comment: In reply to David's answer if I were to place copyarray in the function findsequencex would it make a difference

Comment: You need to throw away all of your code. It makes no sense at all. You cannot get anything useful out of it.

Comment: In response to what has been said sofar I am very disappointed. The concept of parallel programming is not new but new in delphi. I thought I would try to learn this by attempting an interesting example not the usual find a prime number. Although I may be out of my depth it is not constructive just to say throw the code away and start again. Where am I start. Some useful pointers would have been helpful.

Comment: I disagree. I can't see what you can learn from that code. However, I'm not going to argue with you. I've made my views clear. You can choose to heed my advice or not. Obviously that's entirely up to you.

Comment: @JimmyDean When dealing with multiple threads you need to think differently from the start. Often the best thing you can do is take a step back and start again.

Comment: @JimmyDean Parallel programming is not new in Delphi. There are some new features to make the code for certain problems more concise; but basically, you've been able to do parallel programming ever since you could create a thread. And the conceptual problems you have to understand are the same no matter what libraries/language features you use. You need to understand things like: encapsulation, how to manage complexity and separation of concerns ***before*** throwing in the complications specific to parallel programming. Such as: concurrency, race conditions, deadlocks, synchronisation, events